# TestNG gets stuck in IntelliJ when running suite with @BeforeMethod

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I'm having trouble running `@BeforeMethod` `@BeforeSuite` and other `@BeforeXXX` annotated methods at IntelliJ. The same goes for `@AfterXXX` methods.

All tests run, everything completes, I see the output telling me that all tests have run and that "Process finished with exit code 0", which tells me everything went as expected. On the left side of the console I have the TestNG tree which shows me all tests green, the most upper root to be as a yellow ring with a red circle inside with a white dash in the middle. The methods which have to be run before every method have these "wait" circles frozen in place and they keep moving a tiny bit when I change the focus (lets say to the code window or the directory tree).

Is there a workaroud for this issue or are there any patches in sight?

TestNG version: `5.12.1`

IntelliJ version: `2017.2`

Comment: Similar issue was supposed to be fixed in 2017.2: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158871. If it still persists, please file a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a reproducible test case.

Comment: You should really consider upgrading your TestNG version.

Comment: @juherr This is a really great idea. Lets go to the world of corporate bureaucracy and formalism. Not everything is a three class project.

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski Yes, I know such kind of situation but 5.12.1 was released 7 years ago and the next release will be 6.12... At least, if you are stuck with java6 or java5, try to use 6.8.x.